# What is the difference between .get() and .fetch(1)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have written an app and part of it is uses a URL parser to get certain data in a ReST type manner. So if you put /foo/bar as the path it will find all the bar items and if you put /foo it will return all items below foo

So my app has a query like

```
data = Paths.all().filter('path =', self.request.path).get()
```

Which works brilliantly. Now I want to send this to the UI using templates

{% for datum in data %}

### {{ datum.title }}

{{ datum.content }}

```
   </div>
```

{% endfor %}

When I do this I get data is not iterable error. So I updated the Django to `{% for datum in data.all %}` which now appears to pull more data than I was giving it somehow. It shows all data in the datastore which is not ideal. So I removed the .all from the Django and changed the datastore query to

```
data = Paths.all().filter('path =', self.request.path).fetch(1)
```

which now works as I intended. In the documentation it says

> The db.get() function fetches an
>   entity from the datastore for a Key
>   (or list of Keys).

So my question is why can I iterate over a query when it returns with `fetch()` but can't with `get()`. Where has my understanding gone wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking at the docs for the wrong `get()` - you want the [get() method on the Query object](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_get). In a nutshell, `.fetch()` always returns a **list**, while `.get()` returns the first result, or None if there are no results.

Answer (score 4):

`get()` requires (I think) that there be exactly one element, and returns it, while `fetch()` returns a `_list_` of the first `_n_ elements`, where *n* happens to be `1` in this case.